OpenGL pygame cannot get buffers working reliably with vertextPointer and colorPointer
So I'm pretty sure I'm just doing something wrong here with how I'm calling the OpenGL.
I've provided an example below where about 30% of the time it shows the semi transparent vertex colored squares on top of a red background. The other 70% of the time it only shows the red background. I tried commenting out various opengl commands to see if I could get it working reliably. This is my attempt at a "minimum" reproducible example from a much larger program.
I tried adding z coordinates to the points and setting GL_DEPTH_TEST but it made no difference it still doesn't work 70% of the time.
Strangely sometimes it will get in a state where the program will work every other time for afew times but perhaps that's just a coincidence.
Also when it does work it works fine and cycles through all the colors for the different squares until the program terminates, so it makes me think it's something wrong with the initialization or some race condition or something.

import OpenGL.GL as gl
import numpy as np
import pygame as pg
from pygame import locals as pg_locals
import time


class OpenGLWindow:
    def __init__(self):
        self.use_color_buffer = 0

        flags = pg_locals.DOUBLEBUF | pg_locals.OPENGL | pg_locals.RESIZABLE
        self.pg_window = pg.display.set_mode(
            (800, 600),
            flags,
            vsync=1,
        )

        # gl.glTexEnvf(gl.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, gl.GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, gl.GL_MODULATE)
        # gl.glEnable(gl.GL_DEPTH_TEST) # we are disabling this for now because the texture z depth and overlay elements aren't configured right yet.
        gl.glEnable(gl.GL_BLEND)
        gl.glEnable(gl.GL_COLOR_MATERIAL)
        gl.glColorMaterial(gl.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, gl.GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE)
        gl.glBlendFunc(gl.GL_SRC_ALPHA, gl.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)
        # gl.glEnable(gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D)

        # gl.glLoadIdentity()

        self.setup_buffers_2()

    def setup_buffers_2(self):
        self._vertexBuffer = gl.glGenBuffers(1)
        self._colorBuffers = gl.glGenBuffers(3)
        gl.glBindBuffer(gl.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self._vertexBuffer)
        vertices = np.array(
            [0.5, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, -0.5, -0.5, 0, -0.5, 0, 0, -0.5, 0],
            dtype="float32",
        )
        gl.glBufferData(gl.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices, gl.GL_STATIC_DRAW)  # Error
        for n in range(3):
            gl.glBindBuffer(gl.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self._colorBuffers[n])
            colors = []
            for p in range(8):
                for c in range(3):
                    colors.append((p % 4) * 0.25 if c == n else 0)
                colors.append((p % 4) * 0.25)
            print(colors)
            gl.glBufferData(
                gl.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, np.array(colors, dtype="float32"), gl.GL_STATIC_DRAW
            )

    def cleanup_buffers_2(self):
        gl.glBindBuffer(gl.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self._vertexBuffer)
        gl.glDeleteBuffers(1, self._vertexBuffer)
        gl.glBindBuffer(gl.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0)
        for n in range(3):
            gl.glBindBuffer(gl.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self._colorBuffers[n])
            gl.glDeleteBuffers(3, self._colorBuffers)
            gl.glBindBuffer(gl.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0)

    def render_opengl_2(self):
        gl.glClearColor(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
        gl.glClear(gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

        gl.glEnableClientState(gl.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
        gl.glEnableClientState(gl.GL_COLOR_ARRAY)
        gl.glBindBuffer(gl.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self._vertexBuffer)
        gl.glVertexPointer(2, gl.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0)
        gl.glBindBuffer(gl.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self._colorBuffers[self.use_color_buffer])
        gl.glColorPointer(4, gl.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0)
        gl.glDrawArrays(gl.GL_QUADS, 0, 8)

        pg.display.flip()

        self.use_color_buffer += 1
        self.use_color_buffer %= 3


window = OpenGLWindow()

# window.render_opengl_2()
# time.sleep(1)
# window.cleanup_buffers_2()

try:
    for _ in range(30):
        window.render_opengl_2()
        time.sleep(0.1)
finally:
    window.cleanup_buffers_2()


hey @Rabbid76 thanks for your suggestion this seems to fix it..... This was an example taken from a set of opengl examples on a site and modified slightly. I'm kind of shocked that it python opengl allows a None there and then works sometimes and not other times. Shall I answer my own question referencing your comment?

The last parameter of glVertexPointer is of type const GLvoid *. So the argument has to be None or ctypes.c_void_p(0), but not 0:
gl.glVertexPointer(2, gl.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0)
gl.glVertexPointer(2, gl.GL_FLOAT, 0, None)

The same applies to glColorPointer.

Thanks a bunch, this did the trick! And you were so fast too, you basically answered the question within 30 seconds ;) I really wonder why they don't just throw a hard error, is that something related to python evaluating the None as 0 only sometimes but not other times?

The last argument of glVertexPointer is a pointer, so 0 is not a valid value. This is a pointer for reasons of backwards compatibility at a time when it was not yet possible to save the attributes in a buffer.
